# Application Delegate Error while integrating Calendar control into my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I need calendar control so I have found out a calendar suitable for my app on the link below:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244

Now I want to integrate that in my project so I am referencing the project into my app but it leads  to a crash and console shows exception that unknown CalendarAppDelegate.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time I got the answer on my own. Needed to import the xcodeproject file and put **"other linker flags"** in **project settings** as **ObjC** and it is working!